# Horizontal li with bullets won't clear both on outer block

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with getting a set of horizontal bullets for an unordered list working.  The final problem is that the paragraph below is flowing on the end of the ul.

Here is a jsFiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/jFfTt/

The CSS:

```
ul.list-disc-horizontal {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}
ul.list-disc-horizontal li {
  list-style-type: disc;
  float:left;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 0px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nisi neque, sodales at pretium a, semper ac lacus. Etiam posuere lacus vehicula tortor volutpat varius. Donec pulvinar tincidunt metus nec fa hendrerit tincidunt. </p>

<ul class="list-disc-horizontal">
<li>Sed at placerat</li>
<li>Donec pulvinar tincidunt</li>
<li>Nullam ultricies</li>
<li>Proin tincidunt</li>
</ul>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nisi neque, sodales at pretium a, semper ac lacus. Etiam posuere lacus vehicula tortor volutpat varius. Donec pulvinar tincidunt metus nec faucibus. Sed sed laoreet est. Quisque ut vehicula metus. Fusce porttitor turpis id mo hendrerit tincidunt. </p>
```

Comment: Check out twitter bootstraps clearfix class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this using a CSS `:after` pseudo class to clear the floats.

Add the following line of CSS:

```
ul.list-disc-horizontal:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ddmoore/FGbFg/